# Using Google ZX with TS-Node in a single file without package.json or ts-config.json

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to marry Google ZX with TS-Node. I want a single script without a ts-config.json and without local node_modules and without a package.json. Just the convenience of typical single-file "shell" scripts.

Currently, there is no good official documentation for using ZX with Typescript and there are [open discussions](https://github.com/google/zx/issues/467). Perhaps, I can find help here.

I think I'm only failing in the very last step where either Node or TypeScript can't resolve **globally** installed dependencies, such as 'zx'. Does anyone know what configuration I have to add?

This is my current approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S ts-node-esm --compilerOptions='{"module": "es2022"}'

import 'zx/globals';

await $`echo it works ${JSON.stringify(foo(1))}`;


function foo(num: number): number[] {
    return [num, num * 2, num * 3];
}
```

Typescript fails with `Error TS2592: Cannot find name '$'`.

If I install `zx` in `./node_modules`, it works. But I want to avoid this.